# Live stream is gets delayed while processing frame in opencv + python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video, ffmpeg

I capture and process an IP camera RTSP stream in a OpenCV 4.4.0.46 on Ubuntu.
Unfortunately the processing takes quite a lot of time, roughly 0.2s per frame, and the stream quickly gets delayed.
Video file have to save for 5 min but by this delaying video file is saved for 3-4 min only.

Can we process faster to overcome delays?

I have two IP camera which have two diffrent fps_rate(Camera 1 have 18000 and camera 2 have 20 fps)

I am implementing this code in difference Ubuntu PCs

- Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0] on linux
- Django==3.1.2
- Ubuntu = 18.04 and 20.04
- opencv-contrib-python==4.4.0.46
- opencv-python==4.4.0.46

```
input_stream = 'rtsp://'+username+':'+password+'@'+ip+'/user='+username+'_password='+password+'_channel=0channel_number_stream=0.sdp'
input_stream---> rtsp://admin:Admin123@192.168.1.208/user=admin_password=Admin123_channel=0channel_number_stream=0.sdp

input_stream---> rtsp://Admin:@192.168.1.209/user=Admin_password=_channel=0channel_number_stream=0.sdp

vs = cv2.VideoCapture(input_stream)
fps_rate = int(vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
I have two IP camera which have two diffrent fps_rate(Camera 1 have 18000 and camera 2 have 20 fps)

video_file_name = 0
start_time = time.time()
while(True):
    ret, frame = vs.read()
    time.sleep(0.2)     # <= Simulate processing time (mask detection, face detection and many detection is hapning)


    ###  Start of  writing a video to disk          
    minute = 5  ## saving a file for 5 minute only then saving another file for 5 min
    second  = 60
    minite_to_save_video = int(minute) * int(second)


    # if we are supposed to be writing a video to disk, initialize
    if time.time() - start_time >= minite_to_save_video or  video_file_name == 0 :
        ## where H = heigth, W = width, C = channel 
        H, W, C = frame.shape
        
        print('time.time()-->',time.time(),'video_file_name-->', video_file_name,  ' #####')
        start_time = time.time()

        video_file_name = str(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())).replace('.0', '')
        output_save_directory = output_stream+str(int(video_file_name))+'.mp4'


        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'avc1')
        
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_save_directory, fourcc,20.0,(W, H), True)

    # check to see if we should write the frame to disk
    if writer is not None:
        
        try:
            writer.write(frame)

        except Exception as e:
            print('Error in writing video output---> ', e)
```

Comment: if your intention is to create video files of 5 minutes, you can calculate time by video length `num_frames = (5*60*fps)` instead of time.time difference

Comment: @SajanGohil  but I have to do detection faster, so frame delay is also reducing.

Comment: it's not quite clear what your main issue is. If you want to make detection related changes, you should post that piece of code. From this, people can't tell what you are using to do that, like tensorflow, pytorch, opencv etc

Comment: @SajanGohil as frame is delayed by .2 sec from vs.read() to writer.write. So to make a 5 min of video will take 35 min when fps = 7(as your num_frames = (5*60*fps)). I want to reduce time from 35 min to 5 min only so I can get a real time frame from OpenCV.

Comment: For speeding up what your model does, you'll have to use software optimization, model optimization, hardware optimization etc whichever is applicable to the framework your model is in.

Comment: @SajanGohil  Now I am using vidgear python package  which is already multi threaded for software optimization Using SSD and 16 RAM for hardware optimization.   I care for video but as well as real time detection (mask, face, tamper and many more) is also imported as I have to enter in MySQL database that  detection is to happen at that  time. By using this entry I have to show on dashboard to client.

Comment: Multithreading in python still uses single process and core, not sure how vidgear exactly does it, but what you can do is create multiple parallel processes that do the same task and then combine the result. You probably still wont get exact 5minute video processed in 5 minutes. Number of processes depends on number of cpu cores you have, and number of models tht your ram can handle at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options for dealing with this.

1. You can have a separate thread dedicated to reading and storing frames from the RTSP stream in a buffer. Your processing happens in the main thread and will request frames from that buffer which will hand over the oldest frame. This will make sure that you aren't missing any frames. However, since your processing step is very slow compared to the framerate of the cameras, you could end up with thousands of pictures in your buffer which could lead to an "Out of Memory" error.
2. Since you seem to mostly care about creating a video with your processing step and not displaying it in realtime, you can save the 5 minutes of video first (go from read() directly to write() without any processing) and when that's done you can read from that video file and process those frames at your leisure since a delay here won't cause you to skip frames.

Comment: For point 1--→Now I am using vidgear python package                                                                                                                                              which is already multi threaded.                                                                                                        For your 2 point-→ yes I have care for video but as well as real time detection (mask, face, tamper and many more) is also imported as I have to enter in MySQL database that  detection is to happen at that  time. By using this entry I have to show on dashboard to client.

Comment: Am I understanding your second point correctly that you want realtime so that your entries into your SQL database are timestamped correctly? If so, when you save the video you can also save a timestamp along with it. Then when you go back to process it you'll have the correct time. Alternatively, is it ok for you to skip frames to stay as close to realtime as possible? If you use a circular buffer and only process the most recent frame then that will also keep you from falling behind.